# Number of reduced decompositions of the dihedral group $D_6$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, lie-algebras

The Weyl group of $\frak{g}_2$ is the dihedral $D_6$. Let us denote its longest element by $w_0$. How many reduced decompositions does $w_0$ have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weak order of a dihedral group looks like a polygon (see e.g. Figure 3.1 in the book "Combinatorics of Coxeter groups" by Björner and Brenti). Hence there are 2 reduced decompositions of $w_0$ (= maximal chains from bottom to top) in these cases.

Comment: See also http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001585/